# How to convert SQL query result to Lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

```
Select distinct Site 
from Agency 
where AgencyId= 1
```

how to convert this SQL query into Lambda expression.

Comment: I'm always intrigued mostly *why* people want to take perfectly good working SQL, and convert it to LINQ, to add lots of extra runtime layers between your app and the data

Comment: Please ask questions after doing something by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the equivalent method syntax Linq corresponding to this SQL code (and given the little detail we have):

```
Agency.Where(a => a.AgencyId == 1).
       Select(a => a.Site).
       Distinct();
```

Comment: I think you want to use Where(a => a.AgencyId **==** 1)